# SublimeText3でC++のシンタックスを無効化するには？

Tags: sublimetext

C言語による開発を行っているのですが、C言語のヘッダーファイル（*.h）をSublimeText3で開くとC++のシンタックス・ハイライトが適用されてしまいます。
ハイライトがうまく行っていれば別に良いのですが、`#pragma once`以降のハイライトがうまくいっておらずプレインなテキストになってしまっています。
そのたびにC言語のシンタックス・ハイライトに戻しているのですが、これをどうにかしたいです。
一番いいのは`*.h`なファイルを開いたときにC言語のシンタックス・ハイライトが適用されることです。

使っているSublimeText3は`build 4107`です。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。
右下の言語名から「Open all with current extension as ...」をクリックし、言語名をクリックすると、その拡張子のファイルが指定の言語名になりました。